# using hdfs.file() gives an error: attempt to apply non-function

Tags: rhadoop

I have just installed rhdfs and wanted to check how does it works...

I tried this below code:

```
library(hdfs)  
mod <- 2
model <- hdfs.file(mod)
```

I am facing an error:

```
Error in hdfs.file(mod) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Could anyone please help me how what is the issue??

Answer (score 1):

Try using this after loading the 'rhdfs' library:

```
hdfs.init()
```

And then,

```
mod <- 2
model <- hdfs.file(mod)
```